# python read and process a file to create dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have to build a program that reads a file which contains information about revisions made to articles and create two dictionaries from the file. The program will ignore all lines except "REVISION" lines

Each entry in the first dictionary has a key which is an editor and a value which is a set (or list) of articles revised by that editor, i.e.:

```
{editor: {set of articles revised by editor}}
```

Each entry in the second dictionary has a key which is an article and a value which is a tuple (or list) that contains the number of edits and a set (or list) of editors who revised the article, i.e.:

```
{article: (count of edits, {set of editors who revised the article})}
```

Here is what a sample log entry from the file looks like:

```
REVISION 4781981 72390319 Steven_Strogatz 2006-08-28T14:11:16Z SmackBot 433328 
CATEGORY American_mathematicians 
IMAGE 
MAIN Boston_University MIT Harvard_University Cornell_University 
TALK 
USER 
USER_TALK 
OTHER De:Steven_Strogatz Es:Steven_Strogatz 
EXTERNAL http://www.edge.org/3rd_culture/bios/strogatz.html 
TEMPLATE Cite_book Cite_book Cite_journal 
COMMENT ISBN formatting &/or general fixes using [[WP:AWB|AWB]] 
MINOR 1 
TEXTDATA 229
```

Once I've created the dictionaries, I have to make several functions which process the "TOP n EDITORS" and display the editors who have revised the most articles (the username of the editor and the number of articles revised by the editor) and the articles which have been revised the most often, etc.

This is what I have so far:

```
def user_input(editors, articles, filename):
    try:
        file=open(filename)
        count=0
        editors={}
        articles={}
        for line in file:
            record=line.strip().split()
            if record[0]=="REVISION":
                editor_name=record[5]
                article_name=record[3]
                if editor_name not in editors:
                    editors[editor_name]=set({article_name})
                else:
                    editors[editor_name].add({article_name})
                if article_name not in articles:
                    articles[article_name]=set({editor_name})
                    count+=1
                else:
                    articles[article_name].add(editor_name)
       except FileNotFoundError:
           print("file was not found")
           return filename


print("""
Please select one of the following menu options:\n
QUIT
HELP
INPUT filename
TOP n EDITORS
TOP n EDITS
TOP n ARTICLES
""")


command=input("select a menu option: ").split()

if command[0].lower()=="quit":
    exit()
```

I don't know where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "...and every time I try to run my code I get an error" please specify what exactly is the error.

Comment: Also you're using a single `try` without `except` which leads to a syntax error. If you want nothing to be done if the `try` block fails, use `except: pass`